# Ubuntu 12.04 based distros desktop crashes with "Could not write byte: broken pipes"

Tags: 12.04

I enjoy using Second Life and OSgrid.  But every viewer I have tried crashes the desktop with the same error. When I get the error "Could not write byte: broken pipes" it resets back to the login screen.  I do not have an NVIDIA video card.  I have Intel HD 945.  The crashes I get are exactly as described in several bug reports on the nvidia drivers.

> Could not write byte: broken pipes

My hardware is a Sony Vaio VPCEA24FM 4 GB RAM, Intel HD graphics.

I already tried:

- Linux Mint 13 Maya Cinnamon and MATE
- Kubuntu
- Xubuntu
- Ubuntu

… all based on 12.04. They all crash the desktop – whether I use the Second Life viewer, Imprudence or Singularity.

I have regressed my system to 11.10 and have no issues. Never had any issues until I updated and it was a clean install using the above mentioned distros.

Comment: Can you try installing `ubuntu-desktop` and see if that fixes your problem? To install that, run the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: I did indeed try installing ubuntu-desktop along with several others as indicated in the original post. I have reverted back to 11.10 for stability. I may attempt 12.04 again, but will probably switch toe to LMDE. Thanks

Comment: @Clinton - please can you register your account - I've had to merge each of your unregistered accounts.  It makes life easier for yourself since you can then edit and comment & reply directly.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).